# Cannot compile angular app with bootstrap

Tags: angular, twitter-bootstrap

I'm having problems compiling my Angular app when including bootstrap. I'm new to Angular but I've used this before and I thought the below is all I had to do but I can't get it to work.

I installed bootstrap from CLI via Powershell using the following command:

```
npm install bootstrap --save
```

It seems to have installed it as I can see in my node_modules folder.

I've included the Boostrap style line in the [Styles] section of .angular-cli.json

```
  "styles": [
    "../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css",
    "styles.css"
  ],
```

but when I try to start my angular app using `ng serve`, I get the following error:

PS C:\angular\apps\MyApp\MyApp.webapp> ng serve
** NG Live Development Server is listening on localhost:4200, open your browser on http://localhost:4200/ **
Date: 2018-01-22T22:55:02.306Z
Hash: 55d32425f16b07bf6645
Time: 46713ms
chunk {inline} inline.bundle.js, inline.bundle.js.map (inline) 5.83 kB [entry] [rendered]
chunk {main} main.bundle.js, main.bundle.js.map (main) 8.64 kB {vendor} [initial] [rendered]
chunk {polyfills} polyfills.bundle.js, polyfills.bundle.js.map (polyfills) 218 kB {inline} [initial] [rendered]
chunk {styles} styles.bundle.js, styles.bundle.js.map (styles) 14.7 kB {inline} [initial] [rendered]
chunk {vendor} vendor.bundle.js, vendor.bundle.js.map (vendor) 2.3 MB [initial] [rendered]

**ERROR in ./node_modules/css-loader?**
    {"sourceMap":false,"importLoaders":1}!./node_modules/postcss-loader
    ?{"ident":"postcss"}!./node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css
    Module build failed: BrowserslistError: Unknown browser query `>= 1%`
    at error
    (C:\angular\apps\MyApp\MyApp.webapp\node_modules\browserslist\
    index.js:37:11)
    at C:\angular\apps\MyApp\MyApp.webapp\node_modules\browserslist\
    index.js:222:9 at Array.forEach (native)
    at browserslist
    (C:\angular\apps\MyApp\MyApp.webapp\node_modules\browserslist\
    index.js:196:13)
    at Browsers.parse
    (C:\angular\apps\MyApp\MyApp.webapp\node_modules\autoprefixer\lib\
    browsers.js:44:14) at new Browsers
    (C:\angular\apps\MyApp\MyApp.webapp\node_modules\autoprefixer\lib\
    browsers.js:39:28)
    at loadPrefixes
    (C:\angular\apps\MyApp\MyApp.webapp\node_modules\autoprefixer\lib\
    autoprefixer.js:56:18) at plugin
    (C:\angular\apps\MyApp\MyApp.webapp\node_modules\autoprefixer\lib\
    autoprefixer.js:62:18) at LazyResult.run
    (C:\angular\apps\MyApp\MyApp.webapp\node_modules\postcss\lib\
    lazy-result.js:274:20)
    at LazyResult.asyncTick
    (C:\angular\apps\MyApp\MyApp.webapp\node_modules\postcss\lib\
    lazy-result.js:189:32)
    at LazyResult.asyncTick
    (C:\angular\apps\MyApp\MyApp.webapp\node_modules\postcss\lib\
    lazy-result.js:201:22)
    at processing.Promise.then._this2.processed
    (C:\angular\apps\MyApp\MyApp.webapp\node_modules\postcss\lib\
    lazy-result.js:228:20)
    at LazyResult.async
    (C:\angular\apps\MyApp\MyApp.webapp\node_modules\postcss\lib\
    lazy-result.js:225:27)
    at LazyResult.then 
    (C:\angular\apps\MyApp\MyApp.webapp\node_modules\postcss\lib\
    lazy-result.js:131:21)
    at C:\angular\apps\MyApp\MyApp.webapp\node_modules\postcss-loader\
    index.js:129:55
    @ ./node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css 4:14-127
    @ multi ./node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css ./src/styles.css

**webpack: Failed to compile.**

The error disappears when I remove the boostrap line from the [Styles] section.

Any idea what's causing this?

Thanks

Comment: Are you sure the file "../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" exists?

Comment: It does exists. I figured out the problem. I'll post my answer in a sec.

Answer (score 3):

Above approach didn't work for me. When I tried to build the project it couldn't find the package reference and displayed the below error message.

[image]

---

Instead of using "**../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css**" I used "**node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css**" in package reference in **angular.json** and it worked.

Answer (score 1):

version: **Angular 6**

**cli: 6.2.3 (ng --version)**

```
"styles": [
              "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css",
              "src/style.css"              
            ],
```

Answer (score 0):

When following my notes from the tutorial I'm following, I had written down that to install `bootstrap` 3.x, I had to use the following command line:

```
npm install bootstrap --save
```

and to install `bootstrap` 4.x, I had to use the following command

```
npm install bootstrap@next --save
```

but when I opened `package.json` for `bootstrap` I noticed that it was referencing 4.0.

To resolve my problem, I went to my `node_modules` folder and uninstalled the current version of `boostrap`:

```
npm uninstall bootstrap --save
```

and re-installed the highest version before 4.0 i.e.

```
npm install bootstrap@3.3.7 --save
```

This resolved my problem and my app is now running as expected when running `ng server` with the bootstrap style line mentioned in my original post included in [style] question.

Hope this helps other.